# experiment with interlacing to achieve 3d effect

Tags: optics

I am going to attempt an experiment to achieve 3d effect.
I read about autostereoscopy on wikipedia.

I am trying to do this,
[image]

I have already processed image in that format. see the image

[image]

every alternate pixel is of particular eye image.

If I create a black - transparent impression on a sheet then it would show a correct image of either left eye or right eye.

I am thinking of printing image(for example) shown below and cut the white areas on the paper.

after that process I will align that sheet in front of my monitor.

[image]

I wanted to ask is this a good idea or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Since your eyes are oriented horizontally (well,at least *mine* are), you need to do the interlacing (and your grating) as *vertical* stripes, as shown in the top image. You also need to make sure that the geometry is correct: the spacing of the stripes and the distance between the grating and the screen must have the same ratio as the spacing of and the distance to your eyes.

Comment: @DaveTweed my graphics plugin(Tridef) only supports horizontal interlacing. will inclination of eyes do the trick ?

Comment: No, you'll have to write a different plugin.

Comment: @Fennekin why not print on transparent sheet/film? Would save the hassle of cutting.